# deno-fmt set line ending behaviour lf/crlf

Tags: typescript, deno, deno-fmt

I have a project built on **Deno Fresh version 1.5.4**. After running **deno-fmt**, all of my files' line endings are changed to **LF**. What are the options or configurations I can set to define the behavior line ending(CRLF or LF)?

I have tried to change the value of **git config --global core.autocrlf** but still not working.

Comment: See https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/20194 -- Deno formats with lf line endings.

Comment: Thanks @DavidSherret, I was wondering is there are any other options other than changing the codebase options?